# Proof verification of the fact that intersection of two convex regions is convex

Tags: solution-verification, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Here is the question:

> Assume that the intersection of two convex regions of a plane is a nonempty
> set. Prove that it is also a convex region.

The definition of a convex region is given as:

> A region $R$ in the plane is said to be convex if, for all points $A, B ∈$
> $R$, we have $AB ⊂ R$. Otherwise, R is said to be a non-convex region.

Proof:
Let us assume that the intersection of two regions $R$ and $S$ is non-convex. Then, there must be points $A$, $B$ $∈$ $R\cap S$ such that (wlog) $AB$ is not a subset of $R$. Thus, we must have a point $X\in AB$ for which $X\notin R\cap S$. Now, there are three possible cases:
$(i)$ $X\in R-S$
$(ii)$ $X\in S-R$
$(iii)$ $X\in (R\cup S)'$
For case $(i)$, $X\notin S$ and thus $S$ is non-convex by the given definition, resulting in a contradiction. Same goes for (ii), (iii). Thus, the region of intersection is convex.

Comment: It seems over complicated... If you take two points $a,b$ in the intersection, the line between them belongs to $R$ (because $R$ is convex) and also to $S$ (because $S$ is convex). If the line between them belongs to both $R$ and $S$, it belongs to the intersection.

Comment: Thank you for minimizing the proof.

Comment: We don't have case (i) because $X\notin R$ already, so you have no logic for cases (ii) and (iii).

Comment: sorry,actually it is $R\cap S$. I will edit it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a,b\in R\cap S$, then $a\in R$ and $b\in R$, therefore $\underline{ab}\in R$.

If $a,b\in R\cap S$, then $a\in S$ and $b\in S$, therefore $\underline{ab}\in S$.

$\underline{ab}\in R$ and $\underline{ab}\in S$ imply $\underline{ab}\in R\cap S$.

Answer (score 4):

With $AB$ you mean $\overline{AB}$ hence the line segment from $A$ to $B$.

A definition of "convex set" reads as follows:

A set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex when for every $x,y\in A$ we have that the line segment from $x$ to $y$ lies in $A$.

With other words: $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex when for every two $x,y\in A$ we have that $tx+(1-t)y\in A$ for every $t\in [0,1]$.

With this definition a direct proof is very simple.

Let $A, B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be convex. Let $x,y\in A\cap B$.

We have to show that $tx+(1-t)y\in A\cap B$ for every $t\in [0,1]$.

This is immediate as $A$ and $B$ are convex.
(I leave the easy verification of the details to you.)

Comment: It's usually called the _line segment_ from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that also reads much better, I will edit that above.